# create multiple drawn lines

Tags: objective-c, ios

so i need to draw 2 different lines. through another [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975837/drawrect-called-after-creating-a-custom-ui), i figured out how to redraw a line. my question is, if i want to draw 2 lines do i need to have 2 code segments to do it? or is there a way to draw n lines?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"drawRect called");
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.startPoint.x, self.startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.endPoint.x, self.endPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

implementation

```
draw2D *myCustomView = [[draw2D alloc] init];

myCustomView.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
myCustomView.endPoint = CGPointMake(300, 300);
myCustomView.lineWidth = 5;
myCustomView.lineColor = [UIColor redColor];

myCustomView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500);
[myCustomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[self.view addSubview:myCustomView];
[myCustomView setNeedsDisplay];

myCustomView.endPoint = CGPointMake(100, 100);

myCustomView.lineColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[myCustomView setNeedsDisplay];
```

this will just redraw the line. do i repeat the drawRect block for each line i want? so if i want two lines, do i have to do:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    //line1
    CGContextRef context1 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"drawRect called");
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context1, self.lineWidth1);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context1, self.lineColor1.CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context1, self.startPoint1.x, self.startPoint1.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context1, self.endPoint1.x, self.endPoint1.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context1);

    //line 2
    CGContextRef context2 = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"drawRect called");
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context2, self.lineWidth2);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context2, self.lineColor2.CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context2, self.startPoint2.x, self.startPoint2.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context2, self.endPoint2.x, self.endPoint2.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context2);
}
```

or is there a better way to handle drawing my lines?

EDIT: the end goal is to use it with a `UIView` with labels and textboxes i'm using as a form. i want lines to break up the form.

i'm wondering if i should just use these custom draw2D `UIView`s as lines only and place them on top of the `UIView` form, then i can just create multiple "draw2D" `UIViews`?

SOLUTION:

so here is the code i figured out that would work:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [tempDict setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10, 10)] forKey:@"start"];
        [tempDict setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(500, 500)] forKey:@"end"];

        [tempArray addObject:tempDict];

        NSMutableDictionary *tempDict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [tempDict2 setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(400, 10)] forKey:@"start"];
        [tempDict2 setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(500, 500)] forKey:@"end"];

        [tempArray addObject:tempDict2];

        self.pointArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.pointArray count]; i++)
    {
        CGPoint tempPoint = [[[self.pointArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"start"] CGPointValue];
        CGPoint tempPoint2 = [[[self.pointArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"end"] CGPointValue];

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, tempPoint2.x, tempPoint2.y);
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

i included my initWithFrame: method on creating the array that i used for testing (CGPoint's are not objects, so had to figure out how to include them in an dictionary).

so this will loop through and create n lines.

Comment: FYI, you can improve your loop by using "for (NSDictionary *dict in self.pointArray) { ..." then you don't have to look up the object in the array with i each time. This kind of loop is known as "fast iteration" and you can do it with any kind of objects in an array or dictionary.

Comment: interesting, i've used for (id key in NSDictionary) before, but haven't seen this one, i'll look into it. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just repeat this bit as many times as you need (with different coordinates each time obviously).

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.startPoint.x, self.startPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.endPoint.x, self.endPoint.y);
```

The first line of code sets the start point of the line, the second line of code draws it. You don't need to repeat all the rest of the code.

In other words, you can draw multiple lines like this:

```
//set up context
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth1);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor1.CGColor);

//line1
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.startPoint1.x, self.startPoint1.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.endPoint1.x, self.endPoint1.y);

//line 2
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.startPoint2.x, self.startPoint2.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.endPoint2.x, self.endPoint2.y);

//line 3
etc...

//finished drawing
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

You don't need to copy the whole lot each time you draw a line, you can just repeat those two lines of code.

Comment: can you expand on this? i don't seem to follow what you are trying to say.

Comment: k, so i used this idea and just put a loop in my drawRect method. i set a instance array with my start and end points and just loop through that to create as many lines as i need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could refactor out the duplicate code into another method and pass in the variables it needs to draw a line, i.e. the context, colour, start and end points, width

Comment: but wont this just redraw the line instead of drawing a new line?

Comment: What are you wanting to draw? A grid? Use what @skippy suggested, put it in a loop inside drawRect. Dont use iVars for each line. Just have a set of starting points and then during the loop - alter the values - like adding 20 points to the y coordinate to move the next line down 20.... etc

Answer (score 0):

the better and universal way is:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect:(long)lineWidth:(CGColor)color:(CGPoint)pStart:(CGPoint)pEnd
{
    //line1
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    NSLog(@"drawRect called");
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pStart.x, pStart.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pEnd.x, pEnd.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

...

[self drawRect:rect:self.lineWidth1:self.lineColor1.CGColor:self.startPoint1:self.endPoint1];

[self drawRect:rect:self.lineWidth2:self.lineColor2.CGColor:self.startPoint2:self.endPoint2];

...

Comment: won't this redraw the line rather then drawing a new line?

Comment: ah, yes, i guess i didn't think of overloading the drawRect method, i like that approach better then the instance variables, thank you.

Comment: er, i thought we shouldn't call drawRect directly? or am i missing something here?